# Consistency between Office UI Fabric component definitions

Tags: office-ui-fabric

(Disclaimer: I ask this here as it qualifies for a question and they should not be posted on github, and I have very little experience with React)

I'm creating a port of office-ui-fabric-react for Vue, and made really good progress with all the components that use the `styled` function (e.g. Toggle). But I noticed, that a lot of other components don't follow the same structure. There are two variants I encountered so far:

```
export const Toggle: React.StatelessComponent<IToggleProps> = styled<IToggleProps, IToggleStyleProps, IToggleStyles>(
  ToggleBase,
  getStyles,
  undefined,
  { scope: 'Toggle' }
);
```

```
@customizable('SpinButton', ['theme', 'styles'], true)
export class SpinButton extends BaseComponent<ISpinButtonProps, ISpinButtonState> implements ISpinButton {
  ...
}
```

The second variant omits the `.base.tsx` file, but defines the component directly in the `.tsx` file. Is there a difference or a reason as to why they are different? Reading  the code of `styled` and `customizable`, the both pretty much seem to do the same stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Fabric, as an open source framework, has controls that were built at different times. Spin button is an example of a control that was built a while ago and hasn't been upgraded to use our current "styles" approach